# How to allow server to access files but not user?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory with a bunch of files in it & I don't want anybody to be able to access these files by either getting a directory listing or by guessing the file location & typing it in.... it should NOT allow them to download it.

I accomplished this by putting the below in my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

However, I want the user to be able to download the file ONLY IF they access it via a script (which is in a different directory) which will give them the download. At the moment with the above settings it doesn't work.

I thought of putting something like..

```
Allow from domain.com
```

But I'm not 100% sure what that means? Does that check where the REQUEST is coming from & hence it would work if the server requests access to that dir? ...or would it still not work as the user is still using the domain via the other script to access the dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dump the files with an "script" you can store your files outside the documentroot. So you need no htacces file.

Perhaps this is a better workaround.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to redirect the user say to your home page when they try to access your downloadable files inside the folder `sec_files` in this example.

I researched on this when one of my clients who purchased secure download links a codecanyon product asked for a solution to protect a folder that contained images or downloadable.

the .htaccess code is below. this .htaccess file is placed inside the `sec_files` i.e downloadable files folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~sec_files/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.satyamtechnologies.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.satyamtechnologies.net [R,L]
```

See how it works when you access [here](http://www.satyamtechnologies.net/secdown/sec_files/samplepdf.pdf), it will redirect you to home page but when you access it through a php script [here](http://www.satyamtechnologies.net/secdown/example.php) it will let you download the same files.